# PATH variable in linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I was in need of setting a PATH in terminal. I tried ;

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sample
```

it seems ok. but after that I lost another paths i set previously. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add PATH like this :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sample/:$PATH
```

appending $PATH will add the current values set in the PATH.

Comment: +1 I prefer this solution over `PATH=$PATH:...` because usually, you add to the path to make sure you get what you added. If you append to PATH, an executable from an unexpected place might be used.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, however an unsuspecting someone else might execute one of your programs by mistake. Say if you have `/usr/local/sample/ls`, then anywhere you run `ls`, you are running the wrong program. Not to mention the possible security exploits that can come with prepending to `PATH`.

Comment: @Shahbaz: As always, security without knowledge is impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sample`

You assigned PATH a new value (`PATH = VALUE`). What you wanted was to add a new value to PATH (`PATH = PATH + VALUE`).